# how to achieve idempotent behavior in lambda that writes to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, idempotent

I have a AWS lambda that does some calculation and writes output to S3 location. The AWS lambda is triggered by cloudwatch cron expression. Since the lambda can be triggered multiple times, I want to modify lamda  code such that it handles multiple triggers for the lambda.

The only major side-effect for my lambda is writing to S3 and sending a mail. In this case, how do I ensure the lambda executes multiple times but still ensuring idempotent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique id and check on it before processing.
See if the event has one. For example, Sample event for "cron expression" in cloud watch rule suggests that you will get something like this:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "89d1a02d-5ec7-412e-82f5-13505f849b41",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2016-12-30T18:44:49Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/SampleRule"
  ],
  "detail": {}
}
```

In this case your code would read event.id and write that to S3 (say yourbucket/running/89d1a02d-5ec7-412e-82f5-13505f849b41). When lambda is initiated it can list the keys under "yourbucket/running" and see if event.id matches any of them.

If none matches, create it.

It's not bullet-proof solution, you might conceivably run into some race-condition, say if another lambda fires up while AWS is slow in creating the key but fast at launching the other lambda but that is what you have to live with if you would like to use s3.